# Impossible to make a <list <list< int* > > work

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

I have quite a problem I can't solve despite the unreasonable amount of time I spent on. I'd like to have a list< list< int* > >, but it is not working. Here is my code :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   int a=2;
   int b=3;

   list<list<int*>> test;

   list< list<int*> >::iterator it;
   it = test.begin();

   it->push_back(&a);
   it->push_back(&b);

   b=4; //should modify the content of "test"

   for(list <int*>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); it2++) {
      cout << *it2 << endl;
   }
}
```

Using xCode, it compiles but I have a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. I hope you will enlighten me !

Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

`test` is empty, so `test.begin()` is a singular iterator and it is illegal to dereference it. It causes undefined behaviour, similar to that from accessing an array out of bounds.

You need to do this:

```
test.emplace_back();
it = test.begin();
```

This will add a new value-initialized element to `test`, so it will become a one-element list containing a zero-element list. Then `it` will point to that single element.